# Question regarding Python namespaces and function imports: Is it preferable to import only the function you need from a module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, namespaces

So I don't recall where I heard this or read this, but I remember being instructed that it was best practice to import only the needed functions or classes from modules for several reasons.

We should do this

```
from my_module import (needed_function, NeededClass)
from numpy import (arange, nditer, ones, zeros, array ndarray)

needed_function()
NeededClass()

ones
arange(0,16).reshape(4,4)
#etc etc
```

rather than import the module and calling the needed functions

```
import my_module as mm
import numpy as np

mm.needed_function()
mm.NeededClass()

np.ones
np.arange(0,16).reshape(4,4)
#etc etc
```

I was told that the primary reason is that when `module.function` is called Python must search the local namespace for `module` then search the module's namespace for `function`, then continue. This must be done each time `module.function` is called and is potentially very time wasting (for large computations).

The contrasts with directly importing the function because then python only needs to search the local namespace once for that function, a much smaller task than searching a potentially very large namespace, such as numpy or scipy.

Is this correct?

Comment: If you have a tight loop of *fast* functions, then yes, the repeated attribute lookup and add a detectable amount of time to the total cost of the loop. But if that's the case, you can always add an additional local definition like `needed_function = my_module.needed_function`. Which form of import you want is mostly a matter of personal preference.

Comment: If it matters the loops that I am working with may take 1e5 iterations, or may take 1e12 iterations (or more if I want). Even just nanosecond delays really add up.

Comment: Also I am trying to keep memory use to the bare minimum, even though that may only take a few extra bytes or so, it's still 'not best practice' for my application to assign extra variables. It really doesn't matter to me whether I assign more variables or not, I just am trying to consider how python interacts with the namespace. If each new variable creates an extra ns delay, that adds up here.

Comment: If you are that concerned about memory (or nanosecond delays), you shouldn't be using Python at all.

Comment: I'll learn C when I need it. In the meantime I am optimizing the code that I can write now.

Comment: I would like to add that from my experience the delays created by using dozens of specific numpy functions throughout even a few million iterations is __non-trivial__. There are dramatic speed ups to be obtained from minimizing the amount of time python has to spend searching for functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some good answers:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function

Personally for my use case, I'm creating an .exe that needs to be very portable and as small file size as possible. Because of that, I mostly import only single functions where possible.

Comment: Thank you for linking that, Martijn Pieters answers my question almost exactly. For anyone else that reads my question, the takeaway that I have is that python does __have too__ search both the local namespace for the module, then search the module's name space for the desired attribute. This will not be costly for small applications or short runs, but this absolutely will add additional runtime, from simply seconds to hours or days for very large computations.